NameError: name 'torchvision' is not defined
I am relatively new to coding. I am trying to use pytorch for cnn . I have installed all the libraries, the versions are updated in google colab, still having issue with torchvision not being defined
I have tried all that needs to be done, i am just trying to create a dataset of images using torchvision.
Create a dataset object
dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(image_folder_path, transform=transform)
Create a data loader for batching
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)  # Adjust batch size as needed
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 2>()
1 # Create a dataset object
----> 2 dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(image_folder_path, transform=transform)
3
4 # Create a data loader for batching
5 data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)  # Adjust batch size as needed
NameError: name 'torchvision' is not defined

did you actually import torchvision? you need to do that

You have to install torchvision package. After that verify that your installation worked by running import torchvision.
